# How to store records in an array using AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native

Just now I started using AsyncStorage. I tried storing input text value like this:

```
class Sample extends React.Component{ 
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
     this.state = {
      Name:' ',
    };
  }
componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("Name").then((value) =>{
      this.setState({"Name":value})
    }).done();
handleChange(e){
      AsyncStorage.setItem("Name", e.nativeEvent.text)
       this.setState({
         email: e.nativeEvent.text
       })
    }
  render(){
    return(
       <View>
        <TextInput
               style={styles.textContainer}
               value={this.state.Name} 
               placeholder="Name"
               onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
       </View>
   )
}
```

For this it is working correctly, but i want to add a record into an array instead of changing the record every time. I want to push the record into an array and need to display the total array data in the view, (i.e) I need previously avilable data also.

Comment: So you want to store an array via AsyncStorage?

Comment: Yes, i want to store an array via AsyncStorage

Comment: did my answer solves your question?

Comment: No i use react-native-store

Comment: Where's the problem?

Comment: You can use merge (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#mergeitem) or multiMerge (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#multimerge)

Answer (score 52):

## Stringify Array

Use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to store an array as a value via `AsyncStorage`.

#### Store / Stringify

```
const stringifiedArray = JSON.stringify(somearray)
```

#### Restore / Parse

```
const restoredArray = JSON.parse(stringifiedArray)
```

### Usage with `AsyncStorage`

```
 return AsyncStorage.getItem('somekey')
      .then(req => JSON.parse(req))
      .then(json => console.log(json))
      .catch(error => console.log('error!'));

const someArray = [1,2,3,4];
return AsyncStorage.setItem('somekey', JSON.stringify(someArray))
      .then(json => console.log('success!'))
      .catch(error => console.log('error!'));
```

Comment: how about if it is a long array?

Answer (score 6):

**for setting**

```
     AsyncStorage.setItem('name', JSON.stringify(your array));
```

**for getting**

```
  AsyncStorage.getItem('name', (error, result) => {
  this.setState({ name: JSON.parse(result) }, function () {   });});
```

Comment: Thanks it's great !

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers give an applied demonstration of pushing values back to the array (as opposed to completely replacing it). Below is an example:

```
// You will first want to set an initial array:
AsyncStorage.setItem("myNumbers", [1, 2, 3])

// Now if we want to append other values to it.
// It's important to enclose it in bracket (otherwise you'd get an error trying to modify an object)

const arr = [await AsyncStorage.getItem("myNumbers")]
arr.push(15)
AsyncStorage.setItem('myNumbers', arr)
```

If you'd like to get the final result:

```
const modified = await AsyncStorage.getItem("myNumbers")
console.log(modified) //gives us 1, 2, 3, 15
```